# Android layout with fixed size in cm / inches

Tags: android, android-layout

What can be used to make sure the container will always be the same size in cm / inches when developing in android studio?

I need it to be centered in the middle of the screen regardless of what phone/tablet is running on so that the element in the middle is same height/length.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Giving it a fix with and height using ** dp - Density-independent Pixels** will have the same size on different screen.
having it in the middle of the screen depend on your parent ViewGroup like Linear layout, relativeLayout, ConstrantLayout etc.

using

> android:gravity="center" in linear layout put them in the middle

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<View
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="#000000"
    />
```

Comment: Wont this result in different sizes on phones with different screen size / resolution (pixel density) ?

Comment: it will maintain the fixed size set